# Difference between AddPSSnapin() vs RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace( WSManConnectionInfo)?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server, powershell-remoting, exchange-server-2010

I need to connect to an Exchange 2010 server using C# and Powershell.  The Exchange 2007 Docs want me [to add a snap in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332449%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

```
  RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
  PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
  PSSnapInInfo info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out snapInException);
  Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);
  myRunSpace.Open(rsConfig);
```

Other samples on the net want me to use WSMan like this

```
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, "ExchangeServer.ibm.com", 80, "/Powershell", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential);
```

So my questions are:

- What is the effective difference between these techniques?
- Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

In Exchange 2007 you used a management snapin in a local runspace to run the cmdlets. All the changes were made under your credentials.

In Exchange 2010 that changed.  Maintenance is done through a remote session provided by the Exchange server.  The actual changes are done by the Exchange server on your behalf using a proxy account, and Exchange determines whether you're authorized to make those changes according to the RBAC roles you belong to.  The changes are logged in the Admin Audit log.

There is a snapin for Exchange 2010, but using it by adding it into a local session is not supported by MS, and not all of the cmdlets work properly in that environment. Most cmdlets do work, but it bypasses RBAC, and and any changes made in that environment do not get logged to the Admin Audit Log.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is simply instantiating a new Runspace on the local system, which does not use WS-MAN. The second portion is leveraging the WS-MAN service, which requires that you configure it on all of the systems you'll be connecting to ahead of time.

To be honest, if you don't need to use WS-MAN to connect to a remote system, I would just avoid it and use the Exchange team's recommended practice. WS-MAN is (read: can be) fairly simple to set up and use, but it adds a layer of complexity that may simply be unnecessary, and cause additional troubleshooting headaches.

Comment: Do you know if E2010 always uses WSMan under the covers?  My impression is that it does.  For example, I can't use the local admin tools if the WSMan isn't happy and healthy.

Comment: I couldn't tell you -- I'm not an Exchange guy.